# what is the simplest way to convert '2021-11-26 21:47' to Date object with a specific timezone?

Tags: javascript

I know there is date-fns-tz and luxon, but I can't figure out how to do it using CDN only.
So the task is the following:

there is a string as an input (can be different):
`2021-11-26 21:47` and it should return a Date object with the `2021-11-26 21:47 Europe/Moscow` (or the corresponding time in UTC, that doesn't matter.

All my attempts to use luxon for that failed. Will be glad to hear any advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach the timezone and create a date object (might be unreliable based on the implementation in the runtime environment)

```js
let inputString = '2021-11-26 21:47';
new Date(inputString + ' UTC+3')
```

---

In order to conform to standard ISO 8601 you can reformat the date as such (as long as you are sure it will always be in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM`)

```js
new Date(inputString.replace(' ', 'T') + '+03:00')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Date.parse()` in plain js to create a new date using the string as input.

```
let d = new Date(Date.parse('2021-11-26 21:47'))
```

`d` is a Date object that already have the right timezone.

In my case:

```
console.log(String(d)); // Fri Nov 26 2021 21:47:00 GMT-0300 (<country> Standard Time)
```

Comment: This is *non-standard* format for `Date.parse()` so the parsing will be implementation dependent. The ISO 8601 subset that is officially supported is `'2021-11-26T21:47'` - with a `T` between the date and the time part.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it. In that case, if OP wanted to use this option he/she would need to normalize it's string before parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used this convertion and works out great for UTC dates

```
new Date('2021-11-26 21:47').toUTCString() = 'Sat, 27 Nov 2021 02:47:00 GMT'
```